# A bound for the holomorphic function

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f$ be holomorphic from the right half-plane $Re z>0$ to the unit disk. Prove that $$|f'(z)|\leq\frac{1-|f(z)|^2}{2 Re z},$$ for any $z:\ Re z>0$.

I do know that $1-|f(z)|^2$ is the square of the distance from $f(z)$ to $z$ the to unit circle, and $Re z$ is the distance from $z$ to the boundary of $Re z>0$. But how can we relate them by the derivative? Thank you.

Let us fix $z$, and consider $$w=\frac{\zeta-z}{\zeta+\bar z}.$$ Then $Re \zeta>0$ is transformed to $|w|=1$.

Consider 
$$F(w)=f(\zeta)=f(\frac{z+w\bar z}{1-w})$$, we obtain, by Cauchy integral formula, that $$F'(0)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{|\eta|=1}\frac{F(\eta)}{\eta^2}d\eta.$$ Now, $$F'(0)=f'(z)\cdot 2 Re z,$$ and then $$\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{|\eta|=1}\frac{F(\eta)}{\eta^2}d\eta=?$$

Comment: I would try mapping the right half-plane to the unit disc and use Cauchy estimates.

Comment: @mrf Which one is the Cauchy's estimate?

Comment: @XLDD You can find the statement of the theorem [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/326897/4583).

Comment: @AymanHourieh OK, let me just try again.Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

> I do know that $1−|f(z)|^2$ is the square of the distance from $f(z)$ to the unit circle

As a matter of fact, it's not. In any case, conformal maps have their own idea about distance to the boundary, which only loosely agrees with the Euclidean notion of distance.

---

[Schwarz-Pick theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarz_lemma#Schwarz.E2.80.93Pick_theorem) gives $|g'(0)|\le 1-|g(0)|^2$ for any holomorphic  map of unit disk to  itself. Consider the map from your post $$\varphi(\zeta)=\frac{\zeta-z}{\zeta+\bar z}$$
and observe that $\varphi(z)=0$ and $|\varphi'(z)|=1/(2\operatorname{Re} z)$. Applying the Schwarz lemma to $f\circ \varphi^{-1}$ yields 
$$|f'(z)|\, |\varphi'(z)|^{-1}\le 1-|f(z)|^2$$
and the conclusion follows.

Answer (score 0):

This is a version of the Schwartz-Pick theorem. See Preposition 1 in [the article by M.Qazi and Q. Rahman](http://www.degruyter.com/view/j/umcsmath.2011.65.issue-2/v10062-011-0021-6/v10062-011-0021-6.xml).

Comment: I could not open the link.

Comment: @ XLDD : This article can also be downloaded from RapidShare as  [a pdf file](http://rapidshare.com/files/2331117179/v10062-011-0021-6.pdf).

Comment: The article by M. Qazi and Q. Rahman containing the proof of the inequality under consideration is already published online [here](http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/full/10.1080/17476933.2011.626035#.UdRd_ax_S_I).